# forge Viewer - cant below markups be rotated?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-data-management

I was checking example https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=598d7ec14cabf2c1f4dec948
Not sure while I see markups in View state, the model cannot be rotated? Is this by design? Or markups drawn using different shapes cannot be viewed using camera events? If this is possible, show me an example which shows this.

I exactly need similar example where I can have an editor where markups mode can be selected and draw?

Answer (score 1):

It is by design but you can try below to enable navigation when in view mode:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.Utils.showLmvToolsAndPanels(viewer)
markExt.allowNavigation(true)
viewer.navTools.orbittoolsbutton.container.style.display='block'
// then pick the desired tool from toolbar and navigate
```

**Note this is NOT officially supported (since navigation is suppressed by design) and might not work with future releases (works as of 7.12).**

Comment: any other example to share where user can select multiple edit modes like circle, arrow, text, because github code seems bit complicated to me for above one

Comment: try [here](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/tutorial-feature_markup.html) - this is the simplest we got but watch out for a few gotchas in the code there - i didn't put this together and can see something there is not 100% correct ...

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested by this example for 3d markup using the Forge Viewer even though it doesn't have a configuration mode.
https://github.com/apprentice3d/ForgeViewerExtensions

Comment: thank you for the reply. I saw that example earlier, but I need something exactly as the above one where we get an editor to pick different modes and should be able to save those markups.